# Finding points on a parametric curve where curvature changes

Tags: calculus, geometry, curvature, parametrization

I am a engineer working on Wankel motors, where a simil-Reuleaux triangle rotates eccentrically in a 8-shaped form:

[image: Wankel Motor]  (from Wikipedia)

Fascinated by this mechanism, I was studying the meaningful points out of sheer curiosity.

The parametric equations to define the **epitroch** (the external 8-shape) are for eccentricity $f$ and $0\leq t < 2 \pi$:

$$x = \cos(t)+f \cos(3t)$$
$$y = \sin(t)+f \sin(3t)$$

First and second derivatives of the parametric equations return respectively the red and fuchsia points ($f=0.2$ in my drawing):

[image: epitroch]

> QUESTION: Is it possible to calculate analytically the 4 blue points where the curve changes curvature?

I was wrongly assuming they were given by the second derivative, but it is not the case. I am in a cul-de-sac and perhaps I only need to find another hobby.

Comment: If I understand it correctly then you are looking for the points where the [signed curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization) is zero, i.e. where $x'(t)y''(t) - x''(t)y'(t) = 0$.

Comment: @MartinR the signed curvature vanishes 8 times for $t\in[0, 2\pi[$. What would those points be in the figure?

Comment: @PierreCarre: I got something like $0 = 1 + 27 f^2+ 12 f \cos(2t)$, which has four solutions. But I am not sure if my calculation is correct.

Comment: I also got $1 + 27 f^2 + 12 f \cos(2 t)=0$ at the inflection points

Comment: @MartinR You are correct... I just inserted everything in Wolfram but add a typo.

Comment: The solution seems to be $t = k \pi \pm \frac{1}{2} \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{27 f^2+1}{12 f}\right) $ where $k$ is an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [signed curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization) of a parametric plane curve is
$$
 k(t) = \frac{x'(t)y''(t) - x''(t)y'(t)}{(x'(t)^2+ y'(t)^2)^{3/2}} \,.
$$
Since you are only interested in the sign of $k(t)$, it suffices to compute the numerator
$$
\begin{align}
x'(t)y''(t) - x''(t)y'(t) 
&= \bigl( \sin(t)+3f \sin(3t)\bigr)\bigl( \sin(t)+9f \sin(3t)\bigr) \\
&\qquad + \bigl( \cos(t)+3f \cos(3t)\bigr)\bigl( \cos(t)+9f \cos(3t)\bigr) \\
&= 1 + 27 f^2 + 12 f \cos(2t) \, .
\end{align}
$$
If the absolute value of $\frac{1+27f^2}{12f}$ is less than one then the curvature changes its sign exactly where
$$
\cos(2t) = - \frac{1+27f^2}{12f} 
$$
and this equation has four solutions in $[0 , 2 \pi)$, one in each quadrant.

For $f= 0.2$ the first solution (in degrees) is
$$
 t_1 = \frac 12 \arccos\left( -\frac{52}{60}\right) \approx 75.04^{\circ}
$$
and the other three solutions are $180^{\circ}-t_1$, $180^{\circ}+t_1$, $360^{\circ} - t_1$.

Comment: Your speed to find the answer (after I spent a weekend on the problem), tells me my passion for Mathematics is not enough to compensate my ignorance.  
Thank you very much to everybody that discussed and contributed!